# How to give color to a three handle slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I'm trying to make a slider with three handles like [this](http://www.icodeya.com/2014/10/creating-three-handle-slider-with.html). But I would like it to have some color on the background sort of like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ63K.png]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following fiddle.  I made it flexible enough that you should be able to add any number of handles and have it work correctly.  Each of them is styled via the index they're added in (see CSS in the fiddle).

http://jsfiddle.net/xb6rhxtn/17/

If you'd like the first element to not display a background then replacing the first CSS entry with this one should do the trick:

> .ui-slider-index-0 {
>
> ```
> background-color: transparent !important;
> background-image: none;
> ```
>
> }

[image: Slider]

**Note:** It doesn't tolerate resizing very well, but you could hook the resize event and update it then if that's important.